# File download in aspx and MVC mixed mode case

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, download, mixed

The below given codes works perfect for me when i am using it with pure asp.net(aspx) application having redirection and front end in asp net.
Now my scenario is, i have mixed mode application in mvc and asp.net(aspx page)
so i am simply using same page(aspx) for downloading file by calling it from mvc controller method, which is not working .
i have written ajax call in view to call a void method in controller which redirects to aspx page where this code is written , rest of case is as mentioned above.

```
**string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/OnePager.xlsm");
                string id = Request.Params["id"];
                HttpResponse response = this.Response;
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.Clear();
                response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + id + "-One-Pager.xlsm");
                response.WriteFile(path);
                response.Flush();
                response.End();**
```

Here is ajax call

```
if (arrselected.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("ExportProjectOnePager", "controller")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ ID: arrselected[0]}),
                    success: function (output) {
                        if (output.notValid.length != arrselected.length) {
                           alert("success");
                        }

                        if (output.notValid != "") {
                            alert("You do not have permission to see this IDs :" + output.notValid);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

and here is void controller method

```
public void ExportProjectOnePager(string ID)
        {
            string _Path = @"~/Reporting/ProjectOnePager.aspx?id=" + ID;
            Response.Redirect(_Path);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your Ajax call? Also if your method is void, how are you redirecting to another view or page?

Comment: thanks for your quick response and interest, below given is my ajax call from mvc view..

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Your action method is correct. When you press the button or so to make the AJAX call, press F12 and See the error it is giving. Only then i will be able to tell.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where does it fail? Do you get the success alert from your ajax? Have you debugged server side? Does it reach your method?

Comment: I am able to debug the code which is written for writing and downloading file, but it is just coming out without any error, and without downloading anything.. , i am not getting anything in success as i am not returning anything to view, i just simply want to download file

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in the controller method, but you have to change it to return FileResult or FileStreamResult, and copy the code there.

You can also change the controller method to return RedirectResult and inside the code use return Redirect('the aspx page') instead of Response.Redirect and return type is void